PC register does not match crashing form
I got a new Mac this year. My TeX apps were transferred from my old Mac. I just tried
to create a LaTeX document, but TeXworks kept "quitting unexpectedly". The report to Apple said "PC register does not match crashing form". What should I do?
Thanks, David Gluck
Concord, CA

I would probably reinstall those apps especially if there is a big difference between the mac versions.

Did you switch from an intel mac to an arm mac?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Thanks, I reinstalled and it works now.  D. G.
